# Change keyboard Hotkeys?

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys

I bought myself a Logisys BackLit Keyboard, and i want to configure the hotkeys it has (Internet, email, search) to open different programs or to put the computer to sleep. Do I have to have logisys Drivers? Does something like Autohotkey help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what Autohotkey can be used for!

I also like [Key Tweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) for this stuff.

Comment: Key Tweak was really cool. (But it didn't work) But still interesting. And you were right AutoHotkey worked great, just took a while to find the right identification of the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to have logisys Drivers?

in order to make use of 'special keys' on your keyboard you will have to install the drivers, yes.

depending on your keyboard, there may be a piece of software installed with the drivers, that allows you to configure certain keys to your likings.